# Redux Forms submit validation does not set errors messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to make form with submit validation. When I submit form, my `handleSubmit` fired and throw `SubmissionError`, but nothing happens any more.

Submit (just throw error every time):

```
function submit(values)
{
   console.log(values);
   throw new SubmissionError({ password: 'Wrong password', _error: 'Login failed!' });
}
```

Render field from example:

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
     <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
     {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
   </div>
  </div>
 )
```

My form:

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
  render()
  {
    const {  error, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting  } = this.props
    console.log(error);
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>Login</h1>
          <Field name="email" type="text" component={renderField} label="Username"/>
          <Field name="password" type="text" component={renderField} label="Username"/>
           {error && <strong>{error}</strong>}
          <button type = "submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
     )
  }
}

LoginForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'login',
    onSubmit: submit
})(LoginForm);

export default LoginForm;
```

When I press `Submit`, the submit function is called, exception is thrown, but nothing happens else and errors message in form and `renderField` not shown.

Comment: I guess you know this example: http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.11/examples/submitValidation/
I am wondering, why you put the line "onSubmit: submit" in the reduxForm call. You already defined handleSubmit in the form's onSubmit attribute.

Comment: Maybe I can t understand this tutorial. I use `this.props.handleSubmit`, but how I should pass my submit function to the components props?

Comment: Can you add the code of the LoginForm component being used? It should look similar to this: `<LoginForm handleSubmit={submit} />`

Comment: Try removing ```touched &&``` from renderField -> then only it will show error without you touch it

Comment: I do some changes: `<LoginForm onSubmit={submit}/>` but validaton errors still  not shown. If I use `<LoginForm handleSubmit={submit}/>` I've got `submit validation is failed` (yes, I need this!), but It makes  request `?email=xxx&password=xxx` to my server and page reloads (I don't need this)

Comment: Or maybe I can do form myself without redux-forms. How can I do this? I need to make `Action` in `onSubmit` and do request in reducer?

Answer (score 3):

> A throwable error that is used to return submit validation errors from
>   onSubmit. The purpose being to distinguish promise rejection because
>   of validation errors from promise rejection because of AJAX I/O
>   problems or other server errors. [docs](http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/docs/api/SubmissionError.md/)

So, the purpose of `SubmissionError` is not to directly throw an error. Use this when you are doing some `promise` like API request i.e.

```
  return axios
     .post('/sessions/login', values)
     .then((res) => {
           // do something with response
     })
     .catch((err) => {
           throw new SubmissionError(err.response.data);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a validation method to the reduxForm constructor like the following:

```
function validateInput(input) {
  let errors = {}

  if (!data.email) {
    errors.email = "Email is required."
  } 

  if (!data.password) {
    errors.password = "Password is required."
  }

  return errors 
}

const loginForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  onSubmit: submit,
  validate: validateInput
})
```

This will cause redux-form to show the errors under the input field if they are not valid.

Of course you need to connect your component with react-redux connect for this to work like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(loginForm(LoginForm))
```

Comment: this is synchronousValidation pattern not on submit validation pattern